# binascii hexlify decode TypeError: object with buffer protocol required if I use a list with bytes

Tags: list, byte, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

So, I got this wired thing when using list with bytes inside on a Raspberry Pi Pico and MicroPython.

If I use `binascii.hexlify(data_raw[0]).decode()` I got the error *TypeError: object with buffer protocol required*

The list is like below:

```
[b'\x02', b'\x88', b'\x84', b'\x80', b'\x80']
```

Instead, if I use `binascii.hexlify(b'\x02').decode()` everything works fine

I can't understand the issue

Comment: Running into a similar issue (I think). Not necessarily an answer to why, but maybe you can get around it by using `binascii.hexlify(b"{data_raw[0]}").decode()`